# PyLDAvis started giving TypeError: Object of type complex128 is not JSON serializable

Tags: json, typeerror, gensim, pyldavis

Doing Uni assignment on 'One Million Headlines" using LDA analysis in VS Code.

Run the code many times, but just after increasing the number of topics in my LDA and rerunning the code my pyLDAvis code:

```py
#create a visualisation of the topics and their word lists and concordance

# Prepare the visualization
pyLDAvis.enable_notebook()  # Only if you are in a Jupyter environment
prepared_vis = gensimvis.prepare(lda_model, corpus, id2word)

# Display the visualization
pyLDAvis.display(prepared_vis)
```

I get this error

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[36], line 8
      5 prepared_vis = gensimvis.prepare(lda_model, corpus, id2word)
      7 # Display the visualization
----> 8 pyLDAvis.display(prepared_vis)

File ~/.pyenv/versions/3.12.2/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyLDAvis/_display.py:222, in display(data, local, **kwargs)
    218         warnings.warn(
    219             "display: specified urls are ignored when local=True")
    220     kwargs['d3_url'], kwargs['ldavis_url'], kwargs['ldavis_css_url'] = write_ipynb_local_js()
--> 222 return HTML(prepared_data_to_html(data, **kwargs))

File ~/.pyenv/versions/3.12.2/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyLDAvis/_display.py:177, in prepared_data_to_html(data, d3_url, ldavis_url, ldavis_css_url, template_type, visid, use_http)
    170 elif re.search(r'\s', visid):
    171     raise ValueError("visid must not contain spaces")
    173 return template.render(visid=json.dumps(visid),
    174                        visid_raw=visid,
    175                        d3_url=d3_url,
    176                        ldavis_url=ldavis_url,
--> 177                        vis_json=data.to_json(),
    178                        ldavis_css_url=ldavis_css_url)

File ~/.pyenv/versions/3.12.2/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyLDAvis/_prepare.py:464, in PreparedData.to_json(self)
    463 def to_json(self):
--> 464     return json.dumps(self.to_dict(), cls=NumPyEncoder)

File ~/.pyenv/versions/3.12.2/lib/python3.12/json/__init__.py:238, in dumps(obj, skipkeys, ensure_ascii, check_circular, allow_nan, cls, indent, separators, default, sort_keys, **kw)
    232 if cls is None:
    233     cls = JSONEncoder
    234 return cls(
    235     skipkeys=skipkeys, ensure_ascii=ensure_ascii,
    236     check_circular=check_circular, allow_nan=allow_nan, indent=indent,
    237     separators=separators, default=default, sort_keys=sort_keys,
--> 238     **kw).encode(obj)

File ~/.pyenv/versions/3.12.2/lib/python3.12/json/encoder.py:200, in JSONEncoder.encode(self, o)
    196         return encode_basestring(o)
    197 # This doesn't pass the iterator directly to ''.join() because the
    198 # exceptions aren't as detailed.  The list call should be roughly
    199 # equivalent to the PySequence_Fast that ''.join() would do.
--> 200 chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
    201 if not isinstance(chunks, (list, tuple)):
    202     chunks = list(chunks)

File ~/.pyenv/versions/3.12.2/lib/python3.12/json/encoder.py:258, in JSONEncoder.iterencode(self, o, _one_shot)
    253 else:
    254     _iterencode = _make_iterencode(
    255         markers, self.default, _encoder, self.indent, floatstr,
    256         self.key_separator, self.item_separator, self.sort_keys,
    257         self.skipkeys, _one_shot)
--> 258 return _iterencode(o, 0)

File ~/.pyenv/versions/3.12.2/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyLDAvis/utils.py:150, in NumPyEncoder.default(self, obj)
    148 if isinstance(obj, np.float64) or isinstance(obj, np.float32):
    149     return float(obj)
--> 150 return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

File ~/.pyenv/versions/3.12.2/lib/python3.12/json/encoder.py:180, in JSONEncoder.default(self, o)
    161 def default(self, o):
    162     """Implement this method in a subclass such that it returns
    163     a serializable object for ``o``, or calls the base implementation
    164     (to raise a ``TypeError``).
   (...)
    178 
    179     """
--> 180     raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
    181                     f'is not JSON serializable')

**TypeError: Object of type complex128 is not JSON serializable**
```

I don't know why.  Tryied restarting the kernal and updating pyLDAvis with no improvement

Reset the number of topics to the original 10 instead of 25, no change.

What could cause this if all I have done is changed the number of topics for my LDA?

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I've worked with LDA finding a similar issue, unfortunately I'm not able to replicate it, but:

```
**TypeError: Object of type complex128 is not JSON serializable**
```

it seems that for some reasons the LDA generates some complex numbers, so there are 2 options:

> Change the result representation

```
prepared_vis = gensimvis.prepare(lda_model, corpus, id2word, mds='mmds')
```

> Modify the way results are appended in `pyLDAvis/utils.py` (CTRL+click
> on the pyLDAvis to get inside the package), modifing this class as follows:

```
class NumPyEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, np.int64) or isinstance(obj, np.int32):
            return int(obj)
        if isinstance(obj, np.float64) or isinstance(obj, np.float32):
            return float(obj)
        if np.iscomplexobj(obj):
            return abs(obj)
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```